# Active Record .where finds results which dont match requirements

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am trying to grab all entries in my table which have a specific value in one column, but my query returns results with a nil value in that column.

```
Merit::ActivityLog.where(:related_change_type== 'Merit::BadgesSash')
```

returns an entry

```
#<Merit::ActivityLog id: 60, action_id: 102, related_change_type: nil, related_change_id: nil, description: "description text", created_at: "2016-07-12 19:58:05">
```

Comment: Your code doesn't work because of the comparison of symbol to string: `:related_change_type == 'Merit::BadgesSash'`, which would return false. Essentially th query results into: `Merit::ActivityLog.where(false)` which returns all records in the db. See my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your query should be:

```
Merit::ActivityLog.where(related_change_type: 'Merit::BadgesSash')
```

Answer (score 0):

try `Merit::ActivityLog.where(related_change_type: 'Merit::BadgesSash')`. If it doesn't works, a workaround would be `Merit::ActivityLog.where(related_change_type: 'Merit::BadgesSash').reject{|l| l.related_change_type.nil?}`, but not recommended...

Comment: The OP's code doesn't work because of the comparison of symbol to string: `:related_change_type == 'Merit::BadgesSash'`, which would return false. and `Merit::ActivityLog.where(false)` returns all records in the db

Comment: @oreoluwa nice! Thanks for the explanation. Didn't knew .where(false) return all records